# regex: match any unintelligible string inside URL

Tags: python, regex, url

I am looking for any stuff in a URL that would be **non intelligible sequences of characters and/or digits** (*hashes, coded stuff, GUID/UUID...*). I assume that all characters are of type `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`. All positive matches, I'll replace by a specific string `"___ptag___"`. Some examples I found in my dataset:

```
#Positive Matches :
p=["i-IJ0BWanbqz9CojDxJSC3",
"613_18571416_658343_0_12624",
"75ZTZFtTQ15",
"dGhvbWFzLmNvcXVlcnklNDBmcmVlLmZydGh",
"3fd736170ad91c7b59e699fbe7c98e27",
"click8456312324877856p", # even if there is an intelligible word inside, it's a match
"bfjkzahzrfhquchrjghlyuui"]

# negative matches:
n=["sunny_health_fitness_twister_stepper" # words,
"Itunesdotypointappledotypointcom", # words
"2019_01_29", # it looks like a date
"Office-365", # it is intelligible (letters followed by small number of digits)
"id217",      # too small, represents something
"No_Ad_t0",  # too small
"8461531",    # to small
"veri876xx_omg"] # represents something
```

I thought of using this pattern composed of 4 `OR` groups to model my rules:

- anything containing more than 8 consecutive digits, or
- anything longer that 9 char, with 2+ alternate of digit/character, or
- anything longer than 9 char, with 2+ alternate of upper case/lower case, or
- anything longer than 9, with 6+ consecutive consonants.

`import re
[re.findall(r".*\d{9,}.*|(?=.*(?:[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+){2,}).{9,}|(?=.*(?:[a-z]+[A-Z]+){2,}).{9,}|.*(?=[zrtpqsdfghjklmwxcvbnZRTPQDFGHJKLMWXCVBN]{6,}).*.{9,}", i) for i in p+n]`

It almost [does the job](https://regex101.com/r/ITj4CL/2) but it is really not elegant and I'm afraid it might not be robust and might take a long time to match a big dataset. DO you have better ideas to achieve this?
Thanks;

Comment: NOTE: "anything longer than 9, with 6+ consecutive consonants" -> ever heard abour Welsh language? :D

Comment: @Kaddath ok god, no! i'm doomed! :-) well, let's say that I will probably not treat URLs from this language... unless you find a solution to take this into accuont..

Comment: AFAIK RegExs can't distinguish `Barglblargh` from a real word. You will need a dictionary.

Comment: @mumpitz my goal is to find sequences that do not ressemble like anything in human language... so `Baglblargh` is a negative match, clearly, for me. Because in URLs people often put words in somewhat randomly altered ways, so any dictionnary would be useless

Comment: Yeah... I think you're basically asking regex to understand English (or whatever other language might be presented).  You're gonna have fun with that.  A possible alternative might be to verify the data is a `base64` or `UUID/GUID` format or other variants since the "gibberish" you called are usually encoded as such.

Comment: well, let's put it the other way round. If I could have an understanding of my positive matches, it would probably be better. To describe the scturcure of these long digit+character sequences

Comment: You *might* find something like a solution, but the results will *never* be clean.

Comment: You are better off using NLP rather than regex. You will never find something robust enough using regex .